# Error Type "[]" is missing en angular api rest

Tags: javascript, array

estoy creando la parte  del front de mi pagina, consumiendo una api rest de spring boot, me tira el error
Type 'Task' is missing the following properties from type 'Task': idTask, name, idFolder
Aqui mando mi código.

**Clase task**

```
    export class Task{
    idTask:number;`                                
    name:string;
    idFolder:number;
}
```

**task.components**

````
import {Task} from './Task';
import { TaskService } from './task.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-task',
templateUrl: './task.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./task.component.css']
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {

private task:Task[];

constructor(private taskService : TaskService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.taskService.getAll().subscribe(
    res =>{***this.task*** <-- (Aqui me da el error) = res}
  )
}

}```
````

Comment: El mensaje se produce por una inconaistencia de tipado. Revisa el siguiente enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475893/typescript-type-x-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type-y-length-pop

Comment: El mensaje se da por una inconsistencia de tipos. Revisa el siguiente enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475893/typescript-type-x-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type-y-length-pop